# Do teeth have some sort of memory?

Tags: dentistry, mouth, teeth-alignment

I have read of some cases where teeth moved after having been aligned with braces or similar procedures. [Here](https://askthedentist.com/wearing-retainers/#what-happens-if-you-stop-wearing-your-retainer) is one of those sources

> The longer the amount of time since you’ve had braces, the less likely
> your teeth will relapse into their old position.

Therefore, I wonder if teeth have some sort of memory? What causes this movement?

Also, are there preventative measures that can be taken?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalScience.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748), we can not, and will not, give medical advice. If you or someone else has a question regarding personal health, the advice from a doctor should be sought. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta].

Comment: @ChrisRogers thank you for your welcome, however you may want to read the question again, as wanting to know if teeth have some sort of memory is not a question looking for a medical advice.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 that has been an ongoing issue with this website. Your question is obviously not a medical advice.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt There is no issue with the site. The final sentence clearly asks for medical advice. Delete that sentence and it would be okay except it also lacks prior research. The question needs a bit of work.

Comment: I fixed the first problem, but I leave the prior research to the OP.

Comment: @CareyGregory already removed the last sentence. However I have two questions: 1) What does the community mean by medical advice? 2) what prior research is expected to do?

Comment: Medical advice is any question that asks for a personal advice, diagnosis, prognosis, second opinion, or  interpretation of lab results/medical notes/etc. Or more broadly, any question that would require a health professional to know personal details about you (or someone else) to give a proper answer. The prior research requirement basically just means if someone can answer your question with the first results found in google, you should have found that information on your own and included it in your question. It doesn't need to be extensive. Usually a short quote or link will suffice.

Comment: So as an example, I'm fairly sure that if I google terms like orthodontia + tooth movement or something similar, I'd find at least some discussion about it if not an outright answer.

Comment: Your question begins by describing your situation, and then asks what can be done about it. That's asking us a question you should be asking your dentist because no one here knows your history, can examine your teeth, take x-rays, etc. What seems like a correct answer for most people might be wrong for you.That's why we don't allow medical advice questions.

Comment: The question of whether teeth move after braces is one answered by google. If you had shown us the searches you did and said you still didn't understand the results, your question would be perfectly fine. It would also be perfectly fine if you searched and found nothing. Just say, "I searched for X, Y and Z and found nothing." The prior research requirement is one you'll find on all of the science and academic SE sites. It's purpose is to weed out trivial questions with no effort behind them. After all, being required to "show your work" is often a requirement even in high school.

Comment: Meanwhile, instead of debating these points, you could simply edit your question to comply and get it reopened.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @CareyGregory. Already added a reference and [asked a question on meta](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1270/8861).